# Separating and Attaching mesh, Discoloration UV Map

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, edit-mode, color

Guess I should have uploaded a picture of the main issue. The problem wasn't that the meshes were darker without materials. So since that wasn't the issue I've cleared up my question a bit. 
[image]

*So the coat was one big mesh, I separated it at the top of where it discolored now. It wasn't discolored prior to the separation, the coat looked fine all the way down. It happened after I had mirrored one side of the bottom and had reattached it to the coat again. The texture is fine, it just has a blue hue to it. And I don't know how how to fix it, even with the materials removed, it still has that blue hue to it.*

*I tried to recalculate outside and inside which had no effect, other than make it look like it should without material. Just like flipping normals did.
Any ideas? (Hopefully I explained it good enough)*

I found the issue myself yesterday, it's a texture issue. After merging the vertices, the blue area appeared. It's drawing the material from the wrong place in the UV map. How do I go about changing this, in there a way to easily do this, or do I have to move and scale everything by hand?
[image]
In the picture, circled in red. It's supposed to be white, but it's blue since it's taking a texture from another part of the UV map, than the rest.

Comment: I flipped the normals, and it fixed the discoloration when viewing without materials. However, when i put on my materials, it got a blue hue, just like before flipping the normals.

Comment: Normals shouldn't been flipped but recalculated. If mesh has some areas with wrong topology (face sharing an edge with 2 other faces for example) recalculating might not help as well as Blender won't guess which part is inside and which is outside (because technically both will be inside and outside at the same time). If the problem is in the ring of blue-grey faces shown above and recalculating doesn't help them search on dealing with non-manifold geometry

Comment: Now with circled area and more description it's more clear where the problem is. Just assign those faces to another material if you use several of them or select UV islands on UV map corresponding to these faces and move them to appropriate place on UV map